# Razor syntax to declare action that renders html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to create an action that renders some html in the razor view engine.  This was pretty easy in the webforms engine but I'm having some issues with razor.  Here is the simplest form of what I'm trying to accomplish using the webforms engine:

```
<% var myAction = new Action<HtmlHelper<int>>((helper) => { %>
    <div>
        <%= helper.ViewData.Model %>
    </div>
<%}); %>
```

The closest I've come in the razor view engine is:

```
@{var myAction = new Action<HtmlHelper<int>>((help) =>
              {
                    @<div>
                        @help.ViewData.Model
                    </div>;
              });
}
```

This gives a "CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" error.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
    Func<dynamic, object> myAction = 
        @<div>
            @item.ProductName
        </div>;
}

@myAction(Model)
```

You may also checkout the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx).

---

UPDATE:

You may also do this:

```
@{
    Func<HtmlHelper<int>, object> myAction = @<div>@item.ViewData.Model</div>;
}
```

or:

```
@{
    Func<dynamic, object> myAction = @<div>@item.ViewData.Model</div>;
}
```

and to invoke:

```
@myAction(someInstanceOfTheRequiredHelper)
```

Comment: Interesting, but not quite what I need since I need a locally scoped HtmlHelper that is different from the current views htmlhelper.

Comment: @justin, I don't quite understand what you mean by a *locally scoped HtmlHelper*.

Comment: In the example above there is an argument being passed to the Action that is an HtmlHelper<TChild> which is a different helper than the parent HtmlHelper<TParent> that you would normally call with @Html.

Comment: @justin where this `HtmlHelper<TChild>` instance would come from?

Comment: I pass the action into a couple of different html helpers that create it and pass it into the action.

Comment: I was considering doing this; though it will force me to rewrite my html helpers to return a HelperResult.. which I can't seem to find in the mvc framework.  Do you know where it lives?

Comment: It's in the `System.Web.WebPages` assembly which is required by Razor.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in System.Web.WebPages assembly.  Thanks for the help.